# Android SQLite cannot bind argument

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm trying to do a simple query of my database, where a unique Identification number is stored for a PendingIntent. To allow me to cancel a notification set by AlarmManager if needed.
The insertion of a value works fine, but I am unable to overcome the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Database structure: 
    public class DBAdapter {

```
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String TASK = "task";
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "notification";


public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
public static final int COL_NOTIFICATION = 2;


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, TASK, NOTIFICATION};

// DB info: it's name, and the table.
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TaskDB";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CurrentTasks";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key, "
                + TASK + " text not null, "
                + NOTIFICATION + " integer"
                + ");";
```

Now I have created a method to extract the notification ID from the database as needed, using the following code:

```
    public int getNotifID(long notifID){
    String[] x = {ALL_KEYS[2]};
    String[]args = new String[]{NOTIFICATION};
    String where = NOTIFICATION + "=" + notifID;
    int y = 0;
    //String select = "SELECT "+NOTIFICATION+" FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE "+notifID+"="+NOTIFICATION;
    //Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select,new String[]{});
    Cursor c = db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE,x,Long.toString(notifID),args,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (c!= null && c.moveToFirst()){
        y = c.getInt(COL_NOTIFICATION);
    }

return y;
}
```

As you can see I have attempted to do this both with a rawQuery and a regular query, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your raw query to:

```
String select = "SELECT "+NOTIFICATION+" FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE "+NOTIFICATION+"=?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select,new String[]{""+notifId});
if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) {
   c.moveToFirst();
}
c.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I am now getting the error:

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

This is also happening in an alternate method as well.

Comment: Don't use c.getInt(COL_NOTIFICATION). Use c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION)).